# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 34 Incorrect syntax near '.'

Tags: sql-server

I am getting above error while executing query as following, which is a stored procedure command line execution

```
exec sp_Bind_Division_Store_Camera_On_Filter_In_Liveview 
     null, null, null, null
```

Stored procedure is as following

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Bind_Division_Store_Camera_On_Filter_In_Liveview]
    @division varchar(45),
    @store varchar(45),
    @camera varchar(68),
    @group varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
        DECLARE 
            @BaseQuery nvarchar(max) =  'select 
                                            distinct tblcameradetails.name as CameraName,
                                            tblcameradetails.IsDeviceEnabled, 
                                            tblcameradetails.cameraID, 
                                            tblcameradetails.deviceIP, 
                                            tblmediasourcedetails.StreamName, 
                                            tblmediasourcedetails.streamID, 
                                            tblcameradetails.Model_ID, 
                                            tblcameradetails.IsHidden, 
                                            tblcameradetails.hasPTZcapability,
                                            tblcameradetails.CameraModelNo, 
                                            tblcameradetails.username as CameraUserName,
                                            tblcameradetails.hasPTZCycle,
                                            tblcameradetails.hasPreset, 
                                            tblcameradetails.password as CameraPassword, 
                                            tblmediasourcedetails.isRecordingStarted as IsRecordingOn, 
                                            tblcameradetails.IsCovert, 
                                            tblcameradetails.constCameraName, 
                                            tblmediasourcedetails.constStreamName,
                                            tblstoredetails.Store_ID,
                                            tblsystemlocationdetails.division,
                                            tblstoredetails.Store_Name,
                                            tblstoredetails.Store_IP,
                                            tblstoreconfiguration.Liveview_Session_Timeout  
                                        from 
                                            tblmediasourcedetails, 
                                            tblcameradetails, 
                                            tblcameragroupdetails, 
                                            tblgroupdetails, 
                                            tblvssaddsourcedetails,
                                            tblsystemlocationdetails,
                                            tblstoredetails,
                                            tblstoreconfiguration'

    ,   @ParamList nvarchar(max) = N'@p1 varchar(45), @p2 varchar(45), @p3 varchar(68), @p4 varchar(100)'
    ,   @WhereClause nvarchar(max) = N'where 
                                            tblmediasourcedetails.cameraID=tblcameradetails.cameraID 
                                            and tblmediasourcedetails.streamID=tblvssaddsourcedetails.streamID 
                                            and tblcameradetails.cameraID = tblcameragroupdetails.cameraID 
                                            and tblcameragroupdetails.groupID=tblgroupdetails.groupID
                                            and tblstoredetails.Store_ID= tblcameradetails.Store_ID
                                            and tblsystemlocationdetails.Store_ID= tblstoredetails.Store_ID
                                            and tblstoredetails.Store_ID=tblstoreconfiguration.Store_ID and 1=1'
    ,   @OrderByClause nvarchar(100) = 'order by CameraName';

        IF @division IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + ' and division like (@p1)';
        END

        IF @store IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + ' and (store like (@p2))';
        END

        IF @camera IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + ' and tblcameradetails.name like (@p3)';
        END

        IF @group IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + ' and tblgroupdetails.name in (@p4)';
        END

        SET @BaseQuery = @BaseQuery + @WhereClause + @OrderByClause;

        EXECUTE sp_executesql @BaseQuery, @ParamList, @p1 = @division, @p2 = @store, @p3 = @camera, @p4 = @group;

END
```

Now error shows me that on line 34 error at syntax near '.', but I found no problem at all, because I am run this query form command prompt very well same applied in stored procedure, it will raised error. Please help me to solved out this.

Comment: Did you print your @BaseQuery to see what it looks like?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily print your variable `@BaseQuery` to check the resulting query.

the query in the variable  `@BaseQuery` looks like this

```
select 
                                            distinct tblcameradetails.name as CameraName,
                                            tblcameradetails.IsDeviceEnabled, 
                                            tblcameradetails.cameraID, 
                                            tblcameradetails.deviceIP, 
                                            tblmediasourcedetails.StreamName, 
                                            tblmediasourcedetails.streamID, 
                                            tblcameradetails.Model_ID, 
                                            tblcameradetails.IsHidden, 
                                            tblcameradetails.hasPTZcapability,
                                            tblcameradetails.CameraModelNo, 
                                            tblcameradetails.username as CameraUserName,
                                            tblcameradetails.hasPTZCycle,
                                            tblcameradetails.hasPreset, 
                                            tblcameradetails.password as CameraPassword, 
                                            tblmediasourcedetails.isRecordingStarted as IsRecordingOn, 
                                            tblcameradetails.IsCovert, 
                                            tblcameradetails.constCameraName, 
                                            tblmediasourcedetails.constStreamName,
                                            tblstoredetails.Store_ID,
                                            tblsystemlocationdetails.division,
                                            tblstoredetails.Store_Name,
                                            tblstoredetails.Store_IP,
                                            tblstoreconfiguration.Liveview_Session_Timeout  
                                        from 
                                            tblmediasourcedetails, 
                                            tblcameradetails, 
                                            tblcameragroupdetails, 
                                            tblgroupdetails, 
                                            tblvssaddsourcedetails,
                                            tblsystemlocationdetails,
                                            tblstoredetails,
                                            tblstoreconfigurationwhere 
                                            tblmediasourcedetails.cameraID=tblcameradetails.cameraID 
                                            and tblmediasourcedetails.streamID=tblvssaddsourcedetails.streamID 
                                            and tblcameradetails.cameraID = tblcameragroupdetails.cameraID 
                                            and tblcameragroupdetails.groupID=tblgroupdetails.groupID
                                            and tblstoredetails.Store_ID= tblcameradetails.Store_ID
                                            and tblsystemlocationdetails.Store_ID= tblstoredetails.Store_ID
                                            and tblstoredetails.Store_ID=tblstoreconfiguration.Store_ID and 1=1order by CameraName
```

You can see that you are missing a space before the `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` clause

You need to add a space in the starting of your `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` variables like this

```
@WhereClause nvarchar(max) = N' where 
 @OrderByClause nvarchar(100) = ' order by CameraName';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put some `PRINT` in the middle of the query.

For example `PRINT @BaseQuery` after `SET @BaseQuery = @BaseQuery + @WhereClause + @OrderByClause;`

Because maybe you need a space in some variable (for example `N' where...1=1'` instead of `N'where...1=1'` )